# Cannot run Jmeter on my Linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, jmeter

Hey I have tried to run Jmeter (Jmeter-server.bat) on my Linux Terminal but but i get "Command not found". Jmeter is already downloaded from http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi. Tried sh Jmeter.sh , ./jmeter= An error occured:null. What can i do ? By the way i'm doing all this from the lib directory. I tried sh jmeter it says : sh : 0: cannot open jmeter

Answer (score 22, accepted):

OK, I got the solution. I just used the command **./jmeter** -n -t mytextplan.jmx in the bin directory
I wasn't including the "./jmeter" in non GUI mode. It shows i'm in a current working directory.

Then i use

> ./jmeter -n -t TestPlanResult.jmx -l jmeteroutput.csv

to copy results to my csv file.

It worked!!

Answer (score 5):

First - You should have Java installed to run JMeter.

Then, follow these steps.

```
1) Goto http://apache.apache.org/site/downloads/downloads_jmeter.cgi
2) Download Binary 2.11.tgz . The tgz file name will be "apache-jmeter-2.11″
3) Paste it in /usr/USERNAME/Jmeter
4) Unzip “apache-jmeter-2.11″
5) New folder with name “apache-jmeter-2.11″ will be created
6) Go to command prompt
7) go to “apache-jmeter-2.11″ folder (cd /usr/USERNAME/Jmeter/apache-jmeter-2.11)
8) go to “bin” folder (cd bin)
9) Now you are in bin folder (i.e /usr/USERNAME/Jmeter/apache-jmeter-2.11/bin/)
10) type the command “sh jmeter”
11) After a short pause, the JMeter GUI should appear.
```

Slightly modified for you from [this](http://wordpressapi.com/how-to-install-jmeter-on-linux/).

Comment: The upper answer "jmeter" with my other param do not works for me, but 
"sh jmeter" with my other parameter is working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to move to the bin folder.

```
cd ../bin
sh jmeter
```

*.bat files are for windows only, no point trying to run those on linux. jmeter-server is for remote slaves to communicate with a jmeter master, which is also probably not what you want at this stage.

I am assuming you already have a java installation and a desktop environment to run the GUI.

Comment: I ran the command as you gave me it says "An error occurred:null". I have java already installed and a desktop environment

Comment: what does it say in jmeter.log?  what is your environment (ie distro? jre? etc).  try pasting some actual output from the terminal, so we can see exactly what you are trying to do..

Answer (score 0):

I has the very same problem, in my case it was caused by removing Java icon from dock with environmental variable:

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS='-Djava.awt.headless=true'
```

commenting this out in my ~/.bash_profile and restarting terminal fixed it for me.